# Sub query with Recursive search in sql

Tags: sql, subquery, case

Table Item.ItemCategory:

Question-1:

CategoryID         Category        BelongsTo

35             Electronics       0

39             Digital Camera   35
  40             DSLR Lens        39
  41             Canon            40

Question-2:

```
  Concatenate 'category 'column such as Electronics->Digital Camera-> DSLR Lens-> Canon when 41->categoryid is passed
```

Query:

```
Select IC.Category,IC.CategoryID,IC.BelongsTo,
                        case when IC.BelongsTo !=0 then
                        (select IC2.BelongsTo from Item.ItemCategory IC2 where IC2.CategoryID=IC.BelongsTo) 
                        else 
                        IC.CategoryID
                        end as CategoryGroup                                                          
                        from Sales.SalesBillMaster SBM
                        inner join Sales.SalesBillChild SBC on SBC.CBranchId = SBM.BranchID and SBC.CBillNumber= SBM.BillNumber
                        inner join Masters.TaxMaster TM on TM.TaxId=SBC.TaxID 
                        inner join Item.ItemMaster IM on IM.ItemID=SBC.ItemID
                        inner join Item.ItemCategory IC ON IC.CategoryID=IM.ItemCategoryID
                        where  SBM.DeleteFlag<>1 and SBC.DeleteFlag <> 1 and dbo.GetDateToCompare(SBM.BillDate) BETWEEN dbo.GetDateToCompare('10/06/2014') AND dbo.GetDateToCompare('10/06/2014') AND SBM.BranchID in (SELECT * FROM Masters.udf_string_to_table ('1,2',',')) and IC.CategoryID in(41)
```

Incorrect Output:

CategoryID  Category    BelongsTo      CategoryGroup

41           Canon         40              39

Expected Output:

CategoryID  Category    BelongsTo      CategoryGroup

```
41           Canon         40                35
```

Explanation:

```
    As 'canon' belongs to categoryid-40(DSLR Lens) then 40 belongs to categoryid-39
   (Digital camera) then 39 belongs to categoryid-35(Electronics) so if 'canon'
   comes means i need values of 35 in CategoryGroup case column..
   canon categoryid 41->40->39->35 which means we have go bottom to top to find 
   root category..  the root category belongsto column always will be assigned as 0..
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this line

```
(select IC2.BelongsTo from Item.ItemCategory IC2 where IC2.CategoryID=IC.BelongsTo)
```

as this will never provide you with your expected output.
You are getting `BelongsTo` value from `ItemCategory` for `CategoryID = BelongsTo`. In this case your `BelongsTo` is `40`, so the query gives you back `BelongsTo` value for a row that has `CategoryId = 40` and in this case it's:

```
40 DSLR Lens 39 <-- this value
```

You should indeed first write a recursive query that select's the parent of a particular category and then return it's value.

**Edit** For help with recursive queries go [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html).

The simplest way to achieve what you need:
Simple way:

```
WITH abcd(BelongsTo, CategoryId, Category, Level)
AS
(
    SELECT BelongsTo, CategoryId, Category, 0 AS Level FROM ItemCategory WHERE CategoryId = 41
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ii.BelongsTo, ii.CategoryId, ii.Category, Level + 1 AS Level FROM ItemCategory ii, abcd aa WHERE ii.CategoryId = aa.BelongsTo
)
SELECT 
    BelongsTo, 
    CategoryId, 
    Category,
    (SELECT CategoryId FROM abcd WHERE Level = (SELECT max(Level) FROM abcd)) AS CategoryGroup
FROM 
    ItemCategory 
WHERE 
    CategoryId = 41;
```

Hopefully this gives you some insight into CTE / recursive CTE. Please bear in mind that this is not the most efficient way (at least I think so).

Comment: yes you are correct query returns false value on the same line which u have mentioned but i have already tried 'with CTE' and i got same false output..

Comment: If you provide me with `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` statements that cover your example I may be able to help. Just for `ItemCategory`

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ItemCategory](
 [CategoryID] [int] NOT NULL,
 [Category] [varchar](50) NULL,
 [BelongsTo] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

Comment: INSERT INTO [ItemCategory]([CategoryID],[Category],[BelongsTo])VALUES(35,'Electronics' ,0) 
INSERT INTO [ItemCategory]([CategoryID],[Category],[BelongsTo])VALUES(39,'Digital Camera' ,35)      
INSERT INTO [ItemCategory]([CategoryID],[Category],[BelongsTo])VALUES(40,'DSLR Lens ' ,39)   
INSERT INTO [ItemCategory]([CategoryID],[Category],[BelongsTo])VALUES(41,'Canon' ,40)

Comment: Which DBMS and version is this? I get confused with people using [] brackets :)

Comment: sql server 2008 R2    Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 10.50.1600.1

Comment: works perfectly as expected great job and i need concatenate 'category 'column such as Digital Camera-> DSLR Lens-> Canon when canon was choosen how to accomplish this??? if id was mapped with two categoryid means i can accomplish easily but in this case id was mapped with 3 categoryid ...  such as                41    Digital Camera-> DSLR Lens-> Canon     40           35

Comment: You need to build your path recursively meaning that you should add something like `Category AS path` in first `select` and then append `Category` in each recursive call to `path`. You really should be able to write it down yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for Question 1:

```
WITH abcd(BelongsTo, CategoryId, Category, Level)AS(
SELECT BelongsTo, CategoryId, Category, 0 AS Level FROM ItemCategory WHERE CategoryId = 41
UNION ALL
SELECT ii.BelongsTo, ii.CategoryId, ii.Category, Level + 1 AS Level FROM ItemCategory ii, abcd aa WHERE ii.CategoryId = aa.BelongsTo)SELECT 
BelongsTo, 
CategoryId, 
Category,(SELECT CategoryId FROM abcd WHERE Level = (SELECT max(Level) FROM abcd)) AS CategoryGroup FROM 
ItemCategory  WHERE CategoryId = 41;
```

Answer for Question-2:

```
            with category as(select categoryid,category,
                    CAST((category) AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS 'Cg' from item.itemcategory where CategoryId = 41
                    union all
                    select I.categoryid,I.category,
                    CAST((c.Cg + '->' + CAST((I.category) AS VARCHAR(1000))) AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS 'Cg'                              from item.itemcategory I
                    inner join category c on c.categoryid=i.belongsto 
                    and I.CategoryID in(41)
                    )                        
                    select cg  from item.itemcategory c inner join category k on c.categoryid=k.categoryid
```